# Don't understand working of anymodel.findOne.then().catch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, return-value, catch-block

I tried this code to login in my API

```
user.post("/login", (req, res) => {

    let email = req.body.email;
    let password = req.body.password;

    userModel
        .findOne({ $and: [{ email: email }, { password: password }] })
        .then((data) => {
            res.status(200).json({
                text: "User found",
                data: data
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(404).json({
                text: "user not found",
                error: err
            });
        });
});
```

when i send API request in postman with not existing values (email and password) it shows json response below

```
{
    "text": "User found",
    "data": null
}
```

that means findOne doesn't return any error.

then, I changed my code to

```
userModel.findOne(
        { $and: [{ email: email }, { password: password }] },
        (err, data) => {
            if (data) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    text: "User found",
                    data: data
                });
            } else {
                res.status(404).json({
                    text: "user not found",
                    error: err
                });
            }
        }
    );
```

now the json response for not existing credentials is

```
{
    "text": "user not found",
    "error": null
}
```

Why 'then block' is worked in first trial, even the findOne doesn't return any data?
what will MongoDB findOne function return when no data found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#definition):

> If no document satisfies the query, the method returns null.

`catch` block of `Promise` is triggered only when an error occurs (`syntax` error with `mongodb` command etc)

In your `callback` case you're checking `if (data)` which evaluates to `false` since `Boolean(null)` is `false`.

Comment: Yeah right, I should probably link to the `nodejs` connector. or maybe just rename the reference as the node connector frequently refers to `mongodb` manual. For instance `docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/`

Comment: And have a look at mongoose doc (i guess that's what you're using) https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Answer (score 0):

Not finding a record isn't considered error as far as MongoDB is concerned.

The second example works because you are checking if `data` exists rather than relying on there actually being an error - the clue is in the fact `error: null`.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle it that way

```
Model.findOne( {...}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) { ... }
    if (!user) {
        // no user found, do sth
    }
}
```

If no data match the findOne query, then it will return a null value. 
If there's an error, then error object will contain data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What will be considered as Error here?

Comment: Anything that could cause the query to fail... connectivity issue for example

Answer (score 0):

I admit that the [driver docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.2/api/Collection.html#~resultCallback) are not quite descriptive, but the drivers `findOne` behaves exactly like the [shells one](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#definition): It only throws an error if the query is wrong, or the connection to the database goes wrong, if the query succeeds but no document is found, the result will be `null`.